# how to subtract std::map elements from one to other and update it in C++

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, c++03

I am trying to subtract the 1st element of the std::map from every other element of that same std::map. I couldn't find anything about that. Is it possible? for example :

```
std::map<char,int> bar;
bar['a']=11; //should be deleted from other elements
bar['b']=22;
bar['c']=33;
bar['d']=44;

std::cout << "bar contains:\n";
for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=bar.begin(); it!=bar.end(); ++it)
{
  std::cout <<"key: " <<it->first << " Value=> " << it->second << '\n'; //can i delete here??
  //i want to delete value of a from value of b and update the value of b
}
//the new map should be look like as follows
//bar['a']=11; //or may be 0
//bar['b']=11;
//bar['c']=22;
//bar['d']=33;
```

Any ideas to do it easily with map in c++? 
Thanks.

Comment: did you try `it->second = it->second - bar['a']` inside the loop?

Comment: @tobi303, wouldn't `bar.begin()->second` be better than assuming the first key is `'a'`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely as I understand, a map usually isnt meant to imply any specific ordering of the elements, thus for me it seemed more natural to identify the element via its key rather than its position in the map. Anyhow it depends on how it is supposed to be used. I can imagine use cases where `bar.begin()` would make more sense as well as cases where `'a'` would work better

Comment: @tobi303, no, a `std::map` is very definitely ordered, that's one of its core properties. The ordering is very specific and is determined by the third template argument. On the other hand, `std::unordered_map`  doesn't imply any specific ordering (the clue is in the name!) The OP very clearly says "subtract the 1st element" and that is the one pointed to by `bar.begin()`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ok, thanks for clarifying. Nevertheless I wouldnt call it "better", rather "more general" (Note that he also clearly states the the 1st element actually is an 'a'. I know, it is hairsplitting, so nevermind....)

Comment: @tobi303, no, the question talks about the first, the _example_ shows a case where 'a' is the first key, but that's just an example.

Answer (score 3):

**C++11 Solution**

You could use [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) for this

```
std::for_each(std::next(bar.begin()), bar.end(), [&bar](std::pair<const char, int>& x){ x.second -= bar.begin()->second; });
```

For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<char,int> bar;
    bar['a']=11;
    bar['b']=22;
    bar['c']=33;
    bar['d']=44;

    std::for_each(std::next(bar.begin()), bar.end(), [&bar](std::pair<const char, int>& x){ x.second -= bar.begin()->second; });

    std::cout << "bar contains:\n";
    for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=bar.begin(); it!=bar.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << "key: " << it->first << " Value=> " << it->second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output ([working demo](http://cpp.sh/6lds))

```
bar contains:
key: a Value=> 11
key: b Value=> 11
key: c Value=> 22
key: d Value=> 33
```

And if you want to subtract even the first element from itself, just remove the [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) call and capture the value you want to subtract out, since you're going to modify the first map entry.

```
auto const sub = bar.begin()->second;
std::for_each(bar.begin(), bar.end(), [&sub](std::pair<const char, int>& x){ x.second -= sub; });
```

**C++03 Solution**

To subtract the first element from everything *except* the first element itself

```
int value = bar.begin()->second;
std::map<char, int>::iterator it = bar.begin();
std::advance(it, 1);
for (; it != bar.end(); ++it)
{
    it->second -= value;
}
```

To include the first element

```
int value = bar.begin()->second;
for (std::map<char, int>::iterator it = bar.begin(); it != bar.end(); ++it)
{
    it->second -= value;
}
```

Comment: the compiler is showing an error if I use for_each and std::next  but why?? the error says -- **‘next’ is not a member of ‘std’** -- though the headers are same like you. @CoryKramer

Comment: @NazmulHossain Are you using a compiler with C++11 features available?

Comment: I am using **g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5** version. and I have no authority to update it(I think)!! @CoryKramer. any other possible way to use it. Thanks for you quick reply..

Comment: @NazmulHossain Then you will not have access to these C++11 features. See my edit for a C++03 method.

Comment: @NazmulHossain You should also try to bother your computer administrator to upgrade your gcc version, the one you are using is [5 years old](https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html). Tell them the nice people on Stack Overflow suggested it!

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to loop over the map and subtract the value associated with the "first" key from each element, storing the result back into the same element. One approach to that is shown below:

Live example at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bc650592027f5f3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    // Set up the problem...
    std::map<char, int> foo;
    foo['a'] = 11;
    foo['b'] = 22;
    foo['c'] = 33;
    foo['d'] = 44;

    // Obtain the value of the 'a' key...
    const int value = foo['a'];
    // Subtract that value from each element...
    for (auto& element : foo) {
        element.second -= value;
    }

    // Output the map to verify the result...
    for (auto& element : foo) {
        std::cout << element.first << ": " << element.second << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you loop over the entire map, you need to store the initial value of `foo[a]`, since you'll zero it during the iterative subtraction. You can avoid this by using iterators and skipping over the first element using e.g. `std::next(foo.begin())`. Other answers demonstrate this technique, so I won't duplicate it here.

Comment: `const int* value = nullptr; for (auto& elt : foo) if (value) elt.second -= value; else value = &elt.second;`

Comment: And what if the key of the first element isn't `'a'`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely my answer uses the information from the question. Modifications to suit other situations are left as an exercise to the reader, who should be competent enough to recognise this as an example from which to take inspiration, not a copy&paste solution to their problem. I'd say it's far more likely with a map that you want to subtract "the value associated with a known key", than to subtract "the value associated with whichever element is first based on the definition of `operator<`".

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard algorithm `std::for_each` declared in header `<algorithm>`

If your compiler supports C++ 2014 then the code can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::map<char, int> bar;

    bar['a'] = 11;
    bar['b'] = 22;
    bar['c'] = 33;
    bar['d'] = 44;

    for ( const auto &p : bar )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if ( !bar.empty() )
    {        
        std::for_each( std::next( bar.begin() ), bar.end(), 
                       [value = ( *bar.begin() ).second] ( auto &p ) { p.second -= value; } );
    }            

    for ( const auto &p : bar )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
{ a, 11 } { b, 22 } { c, 33 } { d, 44 } 
{ a, 11 } { b, 11 } { c, 22 } { d, 33 }
```

If your compiler supports only C++ 2011 then the main loop in the program can look like

```
if ( !bar.empty() )
{
    auto value = ( *bar.begin() ).second;
    std::for_each( std::next( bar.begin() ), bar.end(), 
                   [value] ( std::pair<const char, int> &p ) { p.second -= value; } );
}
```

The same can be done using for example the range based for loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::map<char, int> bar;

    bar['a'] = 11;
    bar['b'] = 22;
    bar['c'] = 33;
    bar['d'] = 44;

    for ( const auto &p : bar )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if ( !bar.empty() )
    {        
        auto value = ( *bar.begin() ).second;
        bool first = true;
        for ( auto &p : bar )
        {
            if ( first ) first = !first;
            else p.second -= value;
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &p : bar )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Also if the element by which all other elements should be decreased is not necessary the first element of the map then you can use the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::map<char, int> bar;

    bar['a'] = 11;
    bar['b'] = 22;
    bar['c'] = 33;
    bar['d'] = 44;

    for ( const auto &p : bar )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if ( !bar.empty() )
    {
        // the initializer can be any element not only the first one          
        const auto &value = *bar.begin(); 
        for ( auto &p : bar )
        {
            if ( p.first != value.first  ) p.second -= value.second;
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &p : bar )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `bar.begin()->second` instead of `( *bar.begin() ).second`? If Stepanov didn't want us to use `operator->` he wouldn't have given it to us.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely  They are two forms of the same. You may select any you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = bar.begin()->second;

for(std::map<char,int>::reverse_iterator it=bar.rbegin(); it != bar.rend(); it++) {
    it->second -= bar.begin()->second;
}
bar.begin()->second = value;
```

Comment: With your `it=bar.rbegin(); it != bar.rend(); it++)`, you subtract from all elements including the 1st (i.e. setting its value to 0), but the question requests "subtract the 1st element of the std::map from every ***other*** element" (highlighting mine).

Comment: yes, in the question, said //or may be 0, so I don't just don't make begin() to 0